# endIndex is lesser than the length of this String object substring

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a String like below

```
String s = "John21071989Bangalore";

Class Person {
  String name;
  Long dob;
  String city;
  ....
}
```

I have a bean, split string and set the values to Bean.

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setName(s.subString(0,4)); //John
p.setDob(Long.ParseLong(s.subString(4,12))); //2071989
p.setCity(s.subString(12,21));//Bangalore
```

Now my problem is if substring endIndesx is lesser than length giving error.I want to get dob value as null insted error.

```
String s1 = "John2107    Bangalore";

Person p = new Person();
p.setName(s.subString(0,4)); //John
p.setDob(Long.ParseLong(s.subString(4,12))); //this should be null 
p.setCity(s.subString(12,21));//Bangalore
```

Comment: What has length got to do with anything? The error is because of the spaces

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "John21071989Bangalore";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<name>[a-zA-Z]+)(?<dob>\\d*)\\s*(?<city>[a-zA-Z]+)");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
    Person p = new Person();
    if (m.find()) {
        p.setName(m.group("name"));
        String dob = m.group("dob");
        if (dob != null && !dob.trim().isEmpty())
            p.setDob(Long.valueOf(dob.trim()));
        p.setCity(m.group("city"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second scenario, you have:

```
String s1 = "John2107    Bangalore";
```

According to this instruction:

```
p.setDob(Long.ParseLong(s.subString(4,12))); //this should be null
```

You are trying to parse white spaces to a number, so that will give you an exception.

You can either validate that line or surround the block into a try-catch:

Maybe something like this can help you:

Create a method called "parseDob":

```
public Long parseDob(String val) {
   try {
      return Long.ParseLong(val);
   } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      return null;
    }
}
```

Then you can keep with your code:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setName(s.subString(0,4)); //John
p.setDob(parseDob(s.subString(4,12)));
p.setCity(s.subString(12,21));//Bangalore
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two substring methods:

1.substring(int beginIndex)

2.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)

The second one is the one that you use. It basically gets the substring from beginingIndex to endIndex.

Example: "abcdefg".substring(2,4); // return 'cd' c is beginning index and included. However, endIndex 4 which represents 'e' in this exapmle is not included. When you try to use this method to get substring from a beginning index to end of the string you have to enter the endindex bigger than the length of the string and this creates an exception. This is exactly what you are doing.

Instead of using second method use the first one. It just gets the substring from given index to end of the String.

Example: "abcdefg".substring(2); // returns "cdefg"

In conclusion, your code should look like as follows:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setName(s.subString(0,4)); //John
p.setDob(Long.ParseLong(s.subString(4,12))); //2071989
p.setCity(s.subString(12));//Bangalore
```